# use subdirectory as other purpose in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

I have installed laravel in my root of domain, its working fine. However

**I want use one sub directory for other purpose like install admin panel in it. For example I have installed laravel in example.com Now I want install other core PHP admin panel in new sub directory called adminpanel. its like this example.com/adminpanel/**

but when I try to access it, its giving me error called page does not redirect correctly. I have read somewhere that I can achieve it if I modify my .httaccess file but I have not much knowlede of it. Let me know if someone can help me for same.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to share more details, and your attempts. For example, if you assume already that you need to change something in the htaccess file, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Better option is creating an `subdomain` for the `admin dashboard`. Login into your `cPanel` and create a sub domain `adminpanel.example.com` set the path to your new folder.

**Non cPanal**

If you don't have cPanel, You should create `vhosts` for your subdomain in server config `(apache/nginx)`.